# Is it possible to modify library file's source code in Android Studio from Gradle dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, pagerslidingtabstrip

I recently switched from Eclipse to Android Studio and I'm experimenting with [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) library.

Trying to customize the Tab Strip I came across the [Triangle Pager Sliding Tab Strip](http://www.kpbird.com/2014/06/android-triangle-pager-sliding-tabs.html) which suggests to modify the source code of the dependency library. How can I modify the source code of a gradle dependency (in this case and in general)? I don't see any available PagerSlidingTabStrip.java in my project.

Comment: What exactly do you want change? Did you try extending the PagerSlidingTabStrip class in your project?

Comment: your link to tutorial is working and was explained very clearly

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. I need to extend the PagerSlidingTabStrip class and do whatever I want in my own class, right? I got confused because the author kept the same name and I thought I could modify the depended library itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for this to work you have to manually copy/paste the code for PagerSlidingTabStrip.java, into a new class in your own package, make changes in that file and use it exactly as before.

Note: if we want to be precise, this "extension" class does **not** really extend from PagerSlidingTabStrip, it's more of a replacement

Comment: Such a simple solution yet I didnt think of it. Thanks!